# using a test mobile app in order to reference its ID

Tags: android, ios, mobile, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to test a Facebook Ads Management application, for advertising for mobile apps specifically. I don't have a real mobile app but need a mobile app registered on facebook and in ios and android app stores in order to reference its facebook app id when testing ad creation. Is there a way to have a mobile app like this, just for testing purposes?

I registered a MobileTest app on Facebook, but I don't have a mobile app in the stores for the Facebook app to point to.

Answer (score 1):

if you are just testing you can use any other apps available on app store (google play or ios). If you are just checking the functionality or your Code then its a good option. We also don't have any mobile app so we used other play store apps to publish ads (didn't run those ads). Use any app which has fewer downloads.